# How to only underline <span> text element inside an <a> element in CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and I have the following code:

```
<a class="b_author" href="#">
  <img class="b_author-avatar img-circle" src="/images/profile_photo.jpg" width="20" height="20">
  <span class="b_author-username">johndoe</span>
</a>
```

How can I get rid of the underline **on hover**?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
a:hover span { text-decoration: underline; }
```

Comment: Can I also use `a.boost_author:hover span.boost_author-username { }` ? If so, what's the most common thing to do? Do I even need too use `a.` and `span.` ?

Comment: Well I can't comment on specific class names, but yes, if you want the whole collection of elements to be a clickable link, but for only the textual part of the link to be underlined on hover, then the technique I provided is the norm.

Comment: I want to add this rule only for a specific part of my website. Why is it `a:hover` and not `boost_author:hover` ?

Comment: Fine, then do that.  My answer was more general.

Answer (score 2):

Use `text-decoration` property of `a:hover` on `<span>`.

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a span {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<a class="boost_author" href="#">
  <img class="boost_author-avatar img-circle" src="/images/profile_photo.jpg" width="20" height="20">
  <span class="boost_author-username">johndoe</span>
</a>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Restricting the styles only for the classes

```
a.b_author{
  text-decoration: none;
}
a.b_author:hover span.b_author-username{
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

And this for many others elements, general purpose

```
a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover span{
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: For my understanding, does `a:hover span.b_author-username` mean: for all spans with class name `b_author-username` inside a link (with pseudo class hover) apply style `text-decoration: underline`?

Comment: Are `a` and `span` mandatory? Wouldn't it better to use class names instead?

Comment: @Engo Yes, I restricted only to spans and anchors tags. Don't use this, if your class has a global scope, which means anything can use this class

Comment: Other idea is use a.b_author:hover before span... meaning the span b_author-username needs be a children from link b_author